# If you have web sites open on a browser and then connect to a vpn, do those websites get sent to the vpn provider?

Tags: networking, vpn

Do they automatically send all the sites open on the browser through the vpn, or does the traffic not get sent through the vpn until the pages are refreshed?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on if anything loads after you connect to the VPN. If you already have the webpage completely rendered, then there will be no requests from the website being sent to the VPN

Answer (score 0):

When you initiate a VPN you default route will be though the VPN gateway, if it's intended to provide internet access. However, if its just to reach specific subnets on the peer end of the VPN tunnel then the VPN tunnel will be used for that specific subnets.

Although, HTTP uses TCP connection it doesn't keep the connection open after sending all the requested data and upon successfully received by the browser.

Assuming you have the first scenario and HTTP connection behavior it will start sending traffic though the VPN if you refresh or click any hyper link in the page(as this will create a new TCP connection to request that data.